# Method of Coppersmith optimal for multivariate?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, lattices, cryptography

It is shown that Coppersmith method yields optimal integer root extraction for univariate polynomials in https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08065 and a follow up work attempts this for bivariate polynomials https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/108.pdf but seems to fall much short of general result for univariate case.

Is it believed that the Coppersmith method is best possible for multivariate case and what do we know about the multivariate case?

Comment: Optimal ... for doing what?

Comment: The technique cannot be beaten to extract roots.

Comment: OK, so, it's a method for finding roots of univariate polynomials. But multivariate polynomials have an infinity of roots, so, what would "optimal" mean?

Comment: Usually we place a bound on integer roots since only integer roots matter.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. So: Coppersmith's method is a method for finding integer roots of polynomials. Maybe you could edit that into the body of your question?

Comment: Provided details.